# How to stop Resharper toggling between Enumerable.ToList and Select suggestion

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

If I use the Resharper code cleanup function, I'm finding my code ...

```
var personInfos = persons.Select(Mapper.Map<PersonInfo>).ToList();
```

is changed to ...

```
var personInfos = Enumerable.ToList(persons.Select(Mapper.Map<PersonInfo>));
```

But then Resharper makes a suggestion "To extension method invocation" for the `Enumerable.ToList` so the code goes back to ...

```
var personInfos = persons.Select(Mapper.Map<PersonInfo>).ToList();
```

I've checked in the Resharper code editing options, but I can't see where/how I can stop this toggling behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @Matthias may be correct

I've updated to current Resharper, i.e. **2016.1.2** and tried the code ...

```
var personInfos = persons.Select(Mapper.Map<PersonInfo>).ToList();
```

Resharper no longer offers a suggestion

And @Vlad274 this is with my code cleanup `Optimise 'using' directives` and `Shorten qualified references` both still checked

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you'll need to create a custom cleanup profile. The two settings that need to be turned off are highlighted below.

[image: Settings]

By default, the full cleanup has both settings turned on. If either setting is turned on, the cleanup will make this switch.

Comment: If this is really the case, it sounds like a bug to me and you should report it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com. Those two options are clearly not responsible for swapping between static and extension invocation. I have both options enabled, and the usual instance-like invocation is kept.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to upgrading and perhaps a more general solution:

Under the code inspection menu you should have inspection 'Convert static method invocation ... ' there is an option called 'configure inspection severity'. Here you should be able to select: do not show.

Works best of course if you save these preferences into a shared settings file so that all working on this solution share this setting automatically.